# Slackware freeradius install

Tags: freeradius, slackware

I cannot make from source freeradius server.

```
CC src/modules/rlm_krb5/rlm_krb5.c
<command-line>:0:17: error: expected identifier or «(» before numeric constant.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Could you please share your make file?

Comment: Maybe problem with my Slackware. Because i try 2 different version, and have same error. But don`t understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Does freeradius-server from slackbuilds.org fit tour needs? If yes

```
# sbopkg -r
# sbopkg -i freeradius-server
```

or by hands

```
# mkdir /tmp/bld; cd /tmp/bld
# wget http://slackbuilds.org/slackbuilds/14.2/network/freeradius-server.tar.gz
# tar xf freeradius-server.tar.gz
# cd freeradius-server
# . *info
# wget $DOWNLOAD
# bash *Build
# upgradepkg --install-new /tmp/freeradius-server-*t?z
```

Don't forget to read /usr/doc/freeradius-server-*/README.SLACKWARE

1. freeradius-server slackbuild on SBo: 
   http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.2/network/freeradius-server/
2. SBo HOWTO: http://slackbuilds.org/howto/
3. sbopkg package can be downloaded from http://sbopkg.org.

Comment: Thank you. But i install from sbopkg on another server and it be allright. Problem on current server. i try install from source and from sbopkg. I understand why.

Comment: Why not to use binary package from "another server"?